# Mouse cursor sometimes is some pixel over its real position

Tags: unity, 14.04, mouse, cursor

I'm on 14.04 / Unity.

I can't say how to replicate or which are contingent conditions, but sometimes my mouse coursor is some pixel upper than its real position, so if I click on an object, probably I'm clicking on something that is some pixel down.

This issue go away by itself, I can't say how, after a few clicks.

It seems it happens with specific applications, such as `Firefox` and `Thunderbird`...

I need suggestions about how to investigate.

Comment: purge && reinstall the `xsrver-xorg-input-mouse` driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug as reported here. Hope to solve: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1306550

Comment: +1: Happens to me (sometime hundreds of pixels of displacement). The bug seems to be the right one. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

How about writing a simple program that logs your mouse position and click position at the same time and compares them, so you could log your findings into a file.

Maybe it's just a visual glitch caused by your monitor settings or a faulty HDMI/DVI/VGA cable so check that by ressetting your monitor settings (on the monitor) and in your driver to default.

If it's a system wide problem this might work. If it's a app wide (Firefox / Thunderbird) problem, probably the best way is to get into contact with mozilla itself for further investigation.

Comment: It started suddenly and it's not app related, as it occurs even with conky-manager too.

Comment: So the only way to investigate is to use or program something like the program above.